# How can I show the API response on an HTML page in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I show the API response on an HTML page in Node.js?

Here's my code:

```
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                res.write('Code:'+req.body);
                var temp = req.body;
                console.log(req.body)
                res.write('<script>setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "http://localhost:63342/untitled/node_rest_shop/api/login_success.html?_ijt=f37kuelpb06k09ooesdrced6ko" + res.body},5000);</script>');

                res.end();
```

When the response is successful, it should show the next page of HTML.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Do you just want to write out the response's body to console?

Comment: I want to show the data on html page which I get from api response.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to interpolate variables in string

In Javascript it call [Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) use back-tick instead of single quote

```
res.write(`<script>setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "http://localhost:63342/untitled/node_rest_shop/api/login_success.html?_ijt=f37kuelpb06k09ooesdrced6ko${res.body}"},5000);</script>`);
```

Comment: I want to show the data on html page which I get from api response.

Comment: how to show api data on html page? Like I create a login page in html, if success occurs than show next html page with user name.